# Cannot open files with Chinese File names

Tags: libreoffice, language-support, internationalization, chinese

I have a new box and English is the language with which I installed Kubuntu 20.04. On my partition I have English but can type Traditional Chinese with Fcitx. LibreOffice is in English. On the staff partitions they use simplified Chinese.

When I try to open files with Chinese names I get this...The operation on /media/bear/Data/Documents/?????�???.docx was started with an invalid parameter. The same message appears for all users including those using Open Office completely in Chinese.

Files I made on my laptop which was installed with traditional Chinese the files have no problems.

```
bear@bigbear:~$ df -hPT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  3.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2      ext4      219G   34G  174G  17% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G   46M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      vfat      511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1      vfat       29G  312M   29G   2% /media/bear/bear
/dev/sdb1      ext4      3.6T  2.0T  1.5T  58% /media/bear/Data
/dev/sdc2      fuseblk   3.7T  2.6T  1.1T  71% /media/bear/Seagate Backup Plus Drive'
```

Comment: What is the format of the staff partitions? What command (or `fstab` entry) are you using to mount them? I suspect a Windows partition and character encoding issue (GB or something else that isn't utf-8). This may be helpful – Oracle: [Mounting a Local Microsoft Windows Partition on Linux Systems](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0918/localization-13/index.html)

Comment: ext4 (box is all Linux) Mounted on /    mounted from  /dev/sda2 .  Note that this problems also occurs in my partition. thanks for your help I will look at the encoding as I installed with English and may have neglected to install some files causing encoding issues. Tomorrow I will check my laptop and see what Chinese/Internationalization type things are different from my box and my laptop. Thanks again.

Comment: I've only ever seen something like that happen when there are encoding issues or filesystem corruption. You've already tried `fsck`? You could be missing fonts, but that should only prevent seeing the correct filenames, not opening them.

Comment: Its a brand new box. If I rename a .jpg or a .flac file with something in Chinese there are no problems. If I rename a .doc file with a Chinese Characters I get  /media/bear/bear/??????.doc does not exist.

Comment: Can you run `fsck -f` on the problem partitions (`umount` them first)? Also, please add the output of `df -hPT` and `mount` to your question?

Comment: The problem is on all partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you further. Hopefully someone else has some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to KDE settings.

[Take care to the `~/.config/plasma-localerc`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1945819#p1945819)

or maybe alternatively search `locale` in `System Settings` GUI ?

---

And [I guess the region options in the above GUI might not be UTF8 ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316406/1651170)

If so, might try `locale-gen` the other encoding zh_CN/zh_TW locales ?

Or manually edit `plasma-localerc` to be UTF8 ?

---

In my case, I removed all other locales and let only `en_US.UTF-8` left.

Then my `Dbeaver` can detect and open the script with chinese filenames ~ (maybe need restart and refresh)