# Non english file names not shown or incorrectly on Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: kubuntu, files, locale, localization

Non english files are not shown at all or shown incorrectly on many programs. But Dolphin show them fine. What the problem?

Dolphin shows file.

[image: Dolphin]

Double Commander does not show any files.

[image: Double Commander]

Midnight Commander shows question marks.

[image: Midnight Commander]

ls shows codes.

[image: ls]

All programs and OS are last updated from official repo. File system is ext4, where OS is installed. Same happens on NTFS and another ext4.

On Ubuntu 18.04 and Manjaro there was no such problem with these files.

My `/etc/locale.gen` contains these lines uncommented

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

`locale` output:

```
ndp@ndp-G5-5587:~/Documents$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=cv_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="cv_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="cv_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="cv_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: This looks like more of a font issue. I regularly use files that are English, Japanese, Korean, and Thai. So long as the font for Terminal and the file managers is a proper UTF-8-supporting font, there are no issues (for me) 

Comment: What is your current locale?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, added `locale` output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set (probably via the KDE GUI) the `cv_RU.UTF-8` locale which has not yet been generated. Fix that by running:

```
sudo locale-gen cv_RU
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. But I have no idea what is cv and where it comes from. I just selected russian keyboard and formats in the Kubuntu installer. Can you explain please what is cv_RU and should I change it to ru_RU?

Comment: @Dmitry: `cv` is the code for the Chuvash language, so apparently you selected Chuvash as the language somewhere. :) Chuvash is poorly translated, and I suppose your desktop is displayed in English in practice. If you want Russian as the display language, it's indeed a good idea to change the language to Russian.